# How to select SQL Server data based on today's date and time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server to `COUNT` some data which originates from a HTML table. I want to `COUNT` total rows in the database based on today's date. And then after the date hits tomorrow's date, to set the `COUNT` value back to zero and to restart the count back from the start.

Is there a query that can help me fetch data based on current date and time?

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(data_id) 
FROM table1
WHERE clock_time BETWEEN 000000 AND 235959
  AND date_time IS TODAY's DATE (or something like that)
GROUP BY XXX
ORDER BY XXX
```

After the clock hits tomorrow's date, I want to reset the `COUNT` back to zero, and to start a new count back from 00:00:00.

I know there is `NOW()` query but as far as I know it only shows the date.

Someone told me I could use `WHERE DATE(date)=CURDATE()` but the SQL Server won't work with that.

Thank you...

Comment: getdate() returns the date & time; if you have a date in your table, you could compare the date column with getdate() cast to mm/dd/yyyy (or whatever format your date is) to solve the problem

Comment: what is the data type of your `date_time` column ? and does it contains the time other than `00:00` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use convert function like this

```
where convert(Date,date_time)= CONVERT(Date,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

Need not to use time as you want today's data.

Try this one

```
SELECT COUNT(data_id) FROM table1
WHERE convert(date,date_time) = getdate()
```